# I Want to separate grease pencil in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, grease-pencil, render-passes

Is there a Way of isolating the grease pencil like the freestyle pass or cryptomatte?. I can't find a way of doing it.

Comment: Store Grease Pencil objects in Collection and control visibility via View Layers?